# Expand outer div when inner has position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have a problem with an outer div not expanding when the inner div is positioned absolute (inside a div that has position relative).

I tried various variations of clear:both / overflow:xxx / and height: auto. This seems very straightforward to me but it somehow does not work at all as I expect it. I stripped it down to this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class=" infobox">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

And this css snippet:

```
.jumbotron{
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
}
.jumbotron .infobox{
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

What I want to achieve is have the inner div "grow" up from the bottom of the outer div and make the outer one expand accordingly.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks, Dario

Comment: This is not possible. Absolutely positioned elements are removed from document normal flow and the container has no idea about how high or wide they are.

Comment: Only way is to add some js.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for the comments.

This solves it:

```
$('.jumbotron').height($('.infobox').height());
```

In the onload part of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're asking but see if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0bvw1nh/1/) helps you out.

Get and set position and height using JQuery based on each other. Triggered at both the time of creating the document as well as resize of the page. As others have suggested, JavaSCript is needed for such a thing. JS as below:

```
$(function(){
    $('.infobox').offset($('.jumbotron').position());
    $('.jumbotron').height($('.infobox').height());
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.infobox').offset($('.jumbotron').position());
    $('.jumbotron').height($('.infobox').height());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer is very strange but will sure work.

When inner div is in `absolute` position then just add `overflow:hidden` css on your outer div (for example: here *.jumbotron* is the outer div) and you can remove the `min-height` from the outer div, and outer div automatically takes the inner div's height.

(*Make sure outer div should not have any specific height*)